# How to configure Spring Session Redis redisNamespace at runtime

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.6 and Spring Session and Redis as the Session store. I need to be able to set the `redisNamespace` for the application a runtime, and not hard-code it in the code. That means I cannot use `@EnableRedisHttpSession` since that is not something I can set via the `applaction.yml` file.

I've updated Spring Session to 1.2.1.RELEASE to get the support I need, but I cannot seem to get the system to configure the namespace via configuration. I tried using a SPEL in the `@EnableRedisHttpSession(redisNamespace)` call, but that doesn't work. I tried to have the `RedisHttpSessionConfiguration` injected via `Autowired` to set it as well, and that seemed to have been ignored. There was also another reference in another SO post about using `spring.session.redis.namespace` as a property in `application.yml` but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions/tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please note that `spring.session.*` configuration properties were introduced in Spring Boot 1.4 so they are not available in 1.3. OTOH `spring.session.redis.namespace` JVM property suggested in Javvano's answer works because it's [supported by Spring Session itself](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/redis/config/annotation/web/http/RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java#L152).

Answer (score 3):

Declaring `spring.redis.namespace` per [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html#boot-spring-configuration) is not enough.

After setting `@EnableRedisHttpSession()` to `@EnableRedisHttpSession(redisNamespace = "${spring.redis.namespace}")` it worked.
Per the normal functionality to [externalise configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) you can use system environment variables as well, instead of `spring.redis.namespace`.

**Note:** In this case `spring.redis.namespace` corresponds to the `application.yaml` file that looks like:

```
  spring:
    redis:
      namespace: ${REDIS_NAMESPACE:foobar}
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply put a `-Dspring.session.redis.namespace=myKeyName` to VM arguments.
and it is working fine.

[image]

and I'm using spring boot v1.3.5.RELEASE and spring session 1.2.0.RELEASE.